# Cloud Composer- BigQuery job status check failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Cloud Composer DAG is failing to execute update script. It works fine when I try to read a table.
BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404

It tries to execute if I remove this flag **use_legacy_sql=False** and sugesting to execute in Standard mode.

```
INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 7, in <module>
INFO - Subtask:     exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1492, in _run_raw_task
INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 98, in execute
INFO - Subtask:     self.create_disposition, self.query_params)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 499, in run_query
INFO - Subtask:     return self.run_with_configuration(configuration)
INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 868, in run_with_configuration
INFO - Subtask:     err.resp.status)
INFO - Subtask: Exception: ('BigQuery job status check failed. Final error was: %s', 404)
```

Comment: What's the location of your BQ dataset?

Comment: Composer and Dataset are located in europe-west2.

Comment: It works for Select query, but not update. Using BigQueryOperator.

Comment: a *404* is generally a NOT FOUND error, could  you please share a snippet of  you DAG to take a look there?